# How to sort an array that is using map method by props in Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, react-props

I have an array called products that is using the map method to list all the elements inside it and i am trying to sort those elements by the price prop. I've tried all types of sort methods and functions but i can't get it to work.

JS

```
const recentprods = products.map(prod => {
  return <TableRow name={prod.name} price={prod.price} />
})
```

I tried:

```
const recentprods = products.map(prod => {
  return <TableRow name={prod.name} price={prod.price} />
}).sort((a,b) => a.price < b.price)
```

and

```
recentprods.sort()
```

Essentially how could one sort a react component by its props?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should apply the sorting before mapping.

```
const recentprods = products
  .sort((a,b) => a.price - b.price)
      // if you want to change the sorting direction: b.price - a.price
  .map(prod => {
     return <TableRow name={prod.name} price={prod.price} />
  });
```

Comment: If i apply sorting before or after map, i can't access prod.price, prod.name, etc. How would i do that then?

Comment: Should i do another map over the sort method ?

Comment: @Uriel Why you cant access `price` and `name`? They are available inside the map function scope. Just copy and paste my code.

Comment: @Uriel Just updated my answer, probably the gt `>` sign was the issue. The minus operation should sort it out.

Comment: The sort method must return a number not a boolean as shown in my answer. :D

Answer (score 2):

So, yeah basically you need to sort it first and then map it, I've build an example for you:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      products: [
        { name: 'Product 2', price: 2 },
        { name: 'Product 6', price: 6 },
        { name: 'Product 1', price: 1 },
        { name: 'Product 3', price: 3 },
        { name: 'Product 7', price: 7 },
        { name: 'Product 4', price: 4 },
        { name: 'Product 8', price: 8 },
        { name: 'Product 5', price: 5 },
      ],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>ONLY MAPPED</h1>
        {this.state.products.map((prod, i) => {
          return (
            <li key={i}>
              {prod.name} and its price: {prod.price}
            </li>
          );
        })}

        <h1>BOTH SORTED AND MAPPED.</h1>
        {this.state.products
          .sort((first, second) => {
            return first.price > second.price ? 1 : -1;
          })
          .map((prod, i) => {
            return (
              <li key={i}>
                {prod.name} and its price: {prod.price}
              </li>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

[Here you can check out the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbVfi.png)

Answer (score 1):

You want to normalize, sort, and otherwise alter your data as you see fit before applying it to React components. In the following case, the `products` array holds individual objects each with a `price` property, so sort the `products` array beforehand *then* map over the items.

The `.sort` method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the sorted array. The chained `.map` method will iterate over the sorted array in the order prescribed.

I believe the following is a valid solution. Note that price is seen as a `number`. If it isn't, the sort may not work correctly.

```
const recentprods = products
  .sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
  .map(item => <TableRow name={item.name} price={item.price} />);
```

Answer (score 0):

consider we have an array of objects with name and price properties.

const Products =  [

```
{name:"p1",price: 5},
{name:"p2",price: 3},
{name:"p3",price: 2},
{name:"p4",price: 7},
```

]

**We need to sort the Products array in ascending order by using its price property.**

```
console.log(Products.sort((a,b) =>  a.price-b.price )); // descending b.price-a.price

output - >

[
  {name: "p3", price: 2},
  {name: "p2", price: 3},
  {name: "p1",  price: 5},
  {name: "p4", price: 7}
]
```

**Now you can call map function with jsx element you want to add**

```
Products.sort((a,b) =>  a.price-b.price ).map(data => {
   return <TableRow name={prod.name} price={prod.price} />;
});
```

**PS:** YOU can use this function directly in your code or use a helper function this way you make sure its sorted jsx.